# Observable doesn't get the value from store when state got updated

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I want to update my Observable by connect to store but it didn't get updated when store got the value:

In my component, I declared tasks as an Observables:

```js
tasks$: Observable<any> = this.store.pipe(select(state => {
    console.log('state', state);
    return state;
})); // Worked, get the full state

tasks$: Observable<TaskModel[] | undefined> = this.store.select(selectTasks); 
// Doesn't work, can't select tasks from state
```

Reducer:

```js
const tasksReducers = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(getTasks, (state) => ({...state, isLoading: true})),
  on(getTasksSuccess, (state, result) => ({...state, tasks: result.tasks, isLoading: false}))
);
```

Selector:

```js
export const selectTasksState = (state: TasksState) => state;

export const selectTasks = createSelector(
  selectTasksState,
  (state: TasksState) => state.tasks
);
```

Effect:

```js
getTasks$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(getTasks),
      exhaustMap(action => this.tasksService.getTasks().pipe(
        tap(response => console.log('response', response)),
        map(tasks => getTasksSuccess({tasks})),
        catchError((error: any) => of(getTasksFailure(error)))
      ))
    )
  );
```

Actions:

```js
export const getTasks = createAction(TasksActionTypes.GET_TASKS);
export const getTasksSuccess = createAction(TasksActionTypes.GET_TASKS_SUCCESS, props<{tasks: TaskModel[]}>());
export const getTasksFailure = createAction(TasksActionTypes.GET_TASKS_FAILURE, props<{message: string}>());
```

State:

```js
export interface TasksState {
  tasks?: TaskModel[],
  isLoading?: boolean;
  isLoadingSuccess?: boolean;
  isLoadingFailure?: boolean;
}
```

I think the selector didn't see state change so it didn't update, but in the reducer, I already created a new object so I'm not sure where I was wrong

Comment: If you use the `redux dev tools` extension, do you see your state updated in it?

Comment: Yeah, I saw the state got updated after received the Action

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the selectors, I am not sure, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

in TS file

```
selectedData: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedStoreData$ = this.store.select(selectorStoreData);
    
    this.selectedStoreData$.subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data) {
        this.selectedData= data;
      }
    });
 }
```

it will subscribe and store data to selectedData